# Using variables in a function name

Tags: node.js

I have two functions that duplicate their logic and I would like to refactor my code. The values passed as type are either "day" or "night". The functions are:

```
function doBooking(type, rate, nights) {
  if (type=="day") {
    reservation.day(rate, nights, function(err, data) {
      do (a)
      do (b)
      do (c)
    });
  } else {
    reservation.night(rate, nights, function(err, data) {
      do (a)
      do (b)
      do (c)
    });
  }
});
```

I would like to be clever and improve this to be something like the following but it just didn't work...

```
function doBooking(type, rate, nights) {
  ["reservation."+type](rate, nights, function(err, data) {
    do (a)
    do (b)
    do (c)
  });
});
```

Comment: You are almost there. One minor correction and your function will work. Just change `["reservation." + type]` to `reservation[type]`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function doBooking(type, rate, nights) {
  var _type = (type === "day") ? "day" : "night";
  reservation[_type](rate, nights, function(err, data) {
    do (a)
    do (b)
    do (c)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why even bother having separate functions for day/night if they share the same business logic? Couldn't you just add another argument for time of day then?

```
function doBooking(type, rate, nights) {
   reservation.make(type, rate, nights, function(err, data) {
      // (a), (b), & (c) happen inside the reservation handler
      // If you do anything unique to day or night, do it here in the callback of the generic handler
   });
}
```

That aside, there's probably a much cleaner way you can break out the functions here. Start with a defined class for handling a reservation, so you can deal with a known type:

```
function Reservation (type, customer) {
    this.type = type
    this.customer = customer
    this.rate
    this.nights = []
    this.isBooked
    this.make = function(callback) {
        longRunningBookingOperation(this, function(err, data) {
            this.isBooked = data.result === "success" && !err
            callback(err, data)
        })
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
const customer = Customer({firstname: "Tom", lastname: "Jones", id: 2392015572-1827})
var reservation = Reservation(ReservationTypeDay, customer)
reservation.make(err, data) {
    // handle the result
})
```

Comment: `function(err, data) {} // looks like a callback`.
Maybe in the night reservation he is also sending a confirmation email, and it is supposed to wait until the promise is resolved. So I think it makes sense to have different functions to perform the tasks

Comment: Ah, but then _"I have two functions that duplicate their logic"_ would be a false statement. If the business logic is different, and they only share _some_ common code, then a larger refactoring is in order, perhaps passing the business functions themselves as parameters rather than values.

Comment: Ahh, it's unclear. Perhaps "*I have two functions that duplicate their logic*" refers to the callback i.e. function(err, data) {
      do (a)
      do (b)
      do (c)
    }

Comment: Yeah, I dunno. Either way, there are several ways to solve it, and the question is ambiguous.

Comment: The functions are not mine. The are part of a node module I am using.